# Advantages in chess game

Tags: learning

I want to know how I can get advantages in a chess game and what the different types of advantages are, e.g. space and positional advantages?

Answer (score 5):

The question isn't very clear...

An advantage in chess could be many different things:

- Space advantages by the pawn structure
- Pieces mobility/activity
- Pieces coordination
- Strong and weak square
- Pawn structure (isolated pawn, double or tripled pawn, majority or minority, backward pawn on open and/or close line)
- King safety
- Good or bad pieces
- Etc...

There are many forms of advantages, and I certainly forgot some...

And one way to get an advantage is to build on the very small advantages you have in your position at the end of the opening.

For example, in the main line of the King's Indian defense, white has space advantages but the king is under serious pressure.

I hope this helps a bit...

Answer (score 1):

These all could be considered potential imbalances in the Silman universe. Because, you know, that is what chess really is all about.